# webpack use closure-webpack-plugin instead of google-closure-compiler

Tags: webpack, google-closure-compiler

Prior to webpack v4, *closure-webpack-plugin* support wasn't provided, so we had to use *google-closure-compiler*. I'm not sure how to use the plugin.

File: buildSecondary.js

```
var ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').compiler;

function runClosueCompiler(){
    if(!flags.compile)
      return;

    console.log('Compiling');

    var fs = require('fs');

    var closureCompiler = new ClosureCompiler({
      js: 'folder/filename.js',
      compilation_level: 'ADVANCED'
    });

    var compilerProcess = closureCompiler.run(function(exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) {
      //compilation complete 
      if(exitCode === 0){
        console.log('successful');
        fs.writeFileSync('folder/filename.min.js', stdOut);
        console.log('compiled file in folder/filename.min.js');
      }else{
        console.log('complilation exited with code '+exitCode);
        console.error(stdErr);
      }
    });
    console.log('Closure compiler executed successfully');  
}


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('appending module.exports into file/filename.js (import fix)');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var filedata = [
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/file/filename.js').toString(),
    'if(typeof module !== "undefined")',
    'module.exports = filename;'
  ];

  //append to file export
  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/file/filename.js', filedata.join('\n'));

  console.log('Executing closure compiler');
  runClosureCompiler();
}, 2 * 100);
```

File: webpack.config.js

```
var Webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const ClosurePlugin = require('closure-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {

    entry: './folder/entry_file.js',

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'folder'),
        filename: 'filename.js',
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Target Files
                // test: /\.js?$/g,

                // Excluded folders
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,

            },
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new ClosurePlugin({ mode: 'STANDARD'} , 
            { compilation_level: "ADVANCED" })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new Webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),


    ],
};
```

I'm not sure as to what should be changed in the webpack.config.js to build a file similar to buildSecondary.js.

Answer (score 3):

[closure-webpack-plugin has a Webpack v3 version](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/closure-webpack-plugin/tree/webpack-3)

I use it with gulp, like this

*webpack.conf.js*

```js
const ClosurePlugin = require('closure-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    main: './src/global/js/app',
  },
  resolve: {extensions: ['.js']},
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'static')
  },
  plugins: [
    new ClosurePlugin({
      mode: 'NONE',
      closureLibraryBase:
          require.resolve('google-closure-library/closure/goog/base'),
      deps: [
        require.resolve('google-closure-library/closure/goog/deps'),
        './.tmp/deps.js',
      ],
      extraDeps
    },
        devFlags),
  ],
};
```

*gulpfile.js (partial)*

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js');
const closureDeps = require('gulp-google-closure-deps');
// You'll want to connect isDevMode with your build system.
const isDevMode = true; 
const closureDir = path.dirname(
    require.resolve('google-closure-library/closure/goog/base'));

gulp.task('js', ['deps'], () => {
  // If we are in dev mode, do the uncompiled setup.
  if (isDevMode) {
    return gulp.src('')   // Source files have been configred in Webpack
        .pipe(webpack(webpackConfig))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));  // Output files to public folder
  }
});
gulp.task('deps', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/js/**/*.js'])
      .pipe(closureDeps({
        'closurePath': closureDir,
        prefix: '../../../..',
        baseDir: '.'
      }))
      .pipe(rename('deps.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I have some questions. How can I use two builds in webpack config , one for minified version and other for normal in the file, also what's the use of gulpFile in relation to this problem?

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani The gulp file is generating your deps.js, which is a requirement for using this javascript in its uncompiled form. 'Two builds in webpack' sounds like a separate question...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,  although not the perfect answer to my question, but got the gist!

Answer (score 0):

Make webpack recognize goog.require, goog.provide, goog.module and goog.declareModuleId, you can try this [google-closure-library-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-library-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Link only answers are not helpful if the link is broken - Welcome to Stack Overflow :)